# Why do Spaniards have their lunch and dinner so late?

Tags: cultural-history, spain

I've been reading about it and many sites explain (unconvincingly, for me) that the reason why Spaniards currently have lunch around 2 and dinner around 9:30 is because during the 40s (after the civil war), people had to get a couple of jobs to make ends meet and could not keep normal meal times, like in other countries. Spain seem to be the only country in the world with those meal times and the explanation given does not clarify things in the lest. Other countries suffered equally the effects of wars and nothing changed.

Are there any other reasons?

Comment: I'm wondering what you consider "normal meal times". Although there are some [customary meal times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunch#Around_the_world) around the world, you know most people have their own schedule, right?

Comment: Well, I am Spanish myself and "normal meal times" for lunch in the rest of countries are around noon.

Comment: You should probably clarify that you mean historical reasons. Otherwise it might be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Luke, many sites I've read (all in Spanish) say that during the post-war men had to start moonlighting and then meal times had to be changed. Life standards improved in time, but that custom did not change and it's become the norm until today. The question is then relevant to this forum.

Comment: For correction Not only Spanish eat late, moors and arabs too they have three meals 9:00am,1:00pm and 9:oo pm ,but i dont know the reason, maybe both stem from one origin,if they have the same food time table "N Africa and spain" , so the reason is cultural not mathematical .

Comment: Why do you think it is dinner and not supper at 9:30?

Comment: Anixx, Spaniards don't distinguish between "comida" (meal around 2 pm) and "cena" (meal around 9pm) in Spain. Britain does, though: (http://www.englishforums.com/English/DifferenceBetweenDinnerSupper/lmzg/post.htm)

Comment: There are other ountries with those mealtmes. It is exactly the same in Mexico. When kids come home from school everyone eats a big lunch (soup, salad, met etc) and then at ightime here is a lighter dinner. Basically switching what americans eat for dinner in mexico ou eat for lunch.

Comment: What time to people get out of bed in Spain?

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Spain is in the western end of the Central European Time. This means despite the same clock, they have later actual sun cycle (e.g. later actual sunrise, noon, sunset, etc.) than other countries. Human activities are partly [influenced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm) by the sun cycle, so it is logical that their meal schedule is later than the rest of Europe as well.

For example, for 21 October, the solar noon in Madrid is calculated to be [at 13:59](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=141), compared to [12:51](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=37) in Berlin or [12:21 in Warsaw](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=262). Sunset is 17:28 in Warsaw and 19:26 in Madrid. Based on these alone, we can predict that Spaniards would have lunch around 1 hours later than the Germans or 2 hours later than the Poles. And Madrid is still not at the westernmost region of Spain. I believe in Seville it must be even later.

Comment: But then it would be later in Portugal and this is not the case. As I noted above to Yannis Rizos, most people seem to have lunch around noon in every country I know.

Comment: Portugal isn't in CET.. At the same moment while it's 2pm in Spain, it's only 1pm in Portugal

Comment: True, but the meal times have nothing to do with that. Otherwise people in La Coruña o Huelva would eat even later. Besides, when we change the time in spring or autumn, people would also change their meal times.

Comment: @fledermaus I'm not saying it will determine the meal time _to the second_, but the position of the sun does influence human's natural scheduling, including meal times

Comment: Spaniards also tend to go up very early. Explain that with timezones, if you can. ;-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro any reference for that tendency?

Comment: @LouisRhys Me, myself and my sister who lives in Barcelona. And the reason is largely that they don't have lunch, they have siesta, which is several hours long, so they get up early, have a long siesta and work late. It used to be that many worked to 8pm. http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/sep/26/spain-working-hours-ending-siesta But this is changing.

Comment: I was in Galicia (westernmost region of spain) on a sunday morning. It was surreal to walk at 10am, totally empty streets, and see the baker opening his bakery... If the bakery opens at 10am, imagine the rest... - Besides, no way to eat at any restaurant before 2:00 pm, at least we found a brazilian waiter who fixed us sandwiches at 1:00.

Answer (score 14):

I'm kind of surprised nobody has brought up the [Siesta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siesta).

In Spain and many other subtropical and tropical climes they have a tendency to nap during the hottest parts of the day. You'd logically have to then work that much later to put in the same amount of work. That would shift your entire calendar back likewise, including the evening meal.

It's is actually Northern Europeans who are weird in working the whole day through and taking dinner so early. Noel Coward even wrote a rather famous song about it, [Mad Dogs and Englishmen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Dogs_and_Englishmen_%28song%29)

> Mad dogs and Englishmen go out in the midday sun,  The Japanese don´t
> care to, the Chinese wouldn´t dare to,  Hindus and Argentines sleep
> firmly from twelve to one. But Englishmen detest-a siesta.
>
> In the
> Philippines they have lovely screens to protect you from the glare.
> In the Malay States, there are hats like plates which the Britishers
> won't wear.  At twelve noon the natives swoon and no further work is
> done,  but mad dogs and Englishmen go out in the midday sun.

Comment: Siesta is a very common custom in the Indian state of Orissa --where it gets incredibly hot (even by the subcontinent's standards) during the day. They also have some fermented rice dishes on their lunch menu and during my trip there I felt a need to take a nap in the afternoon. My guide explained to it was the rice but it could very well have been the temperature outside.

Comment: I'm not sure "siesta" applies in this case. Mostly because having a nap is not so common as travel guides may lead you to think. It may be during summer holidays when people have _free time_ and yes, August, can be quite unbearable in some areas. My question is still related to meal times throughout the year. Italy and Portugal would have similar temperatures and a incredibly similar culture, but the meal times are earlier.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Source: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/sep/26/spain-working-hours-ending-siesta (there are many other sources if you search for "spain working hours" or similar). But yes, fledermaus has a point in that it's not the *nap* that is the issue, but the long break in working hours associated with the siesta.

Comment: While it is not my intent to disagree with the claim made, it is incorrect to refer to Spain as in a "subtropical" or "tropical clime". Madrid and New York City are at about the same latitude.

Comment: Although I see the point in this answer, I believe it relies on a false assumption. I am with @fledermaus here, *siesta* is not as common as people think it is. I can't talk about southern Spain, but where I come from (Basque Country, northern Spain), *siesta* is uncommon throughout the entire year, maybe with the exception of summer holidays.

Comment: This is certainly true for China. Everyone naps from lunch to 3, with and early lunch.

Comment: I don't see how having a meal at 12 AM and taking a nap are anyhow incompatible (and that's exactly what I routinely do).

Answer (score 5):

Most think of the later dinner time as stemming from the need to ensure that all family members are home to eat together - which is an important tradition of cohesiveness and family-focus.

[This article](http://www.study-in-italy.it/about/eating.html) cites the later dinner-time in Italy as stemming from the long days that people spend out of the home - by implication, earning wage via the livelihood.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Latin and Mediterranean countries have that tradition but all of them (except Spain) still have lunch and dinner earlier.

Comment: It could also be due to the heat.  Spain is more arid, esp. toward the south.  Indians and arabs tend toward a later dinner because the heat accumulated during the day pacifies the appetite.  This is why Indian restaurants will tend to have hours until 1-2am.  Spain, as well, is a country with an extensive Moorish/muslim history, and so may have reconciled toward a later time for these reasons.

Comment: @fledermaus Shops and some offices in southern Italy frequently close from 12 till 4 (the heat really is debilitating) and then open again till 8.  Allowing for travel time & preparation they aren't likely to eat before 9, so your assertion that it's only Spain is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Countries that produced olive oil in classical times stayed up late because this fuel for oil lamps was cheap ( North Africa & Spain ). In Rome and many other places it was expensive and so people got up with the light and tended to go to bed when it gets dark. This is the norm in many counties around the world.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the assertion that Rome didn't have olive oil.

Comment: Of course they did but it was all imported and therefore more expensive. However the Roman Empire was fuelled by it and a huge hill in Rome is completely made up of broken amphora of olive oil which came from Spain and as they were not glazed could not be used twice.

Answer (score -1):

In 1942, General Franco changed Spain's time zone to align with Germany's time zone (because Spain and Germany were allied. It is still functioning today with the same timezone, hence, it gets darker later than it should. Perhaps this can be ONE of many reasons why they have lunch and dinner a little later. It'd be interesting to know if they had the same customs before the time zone change was made...

Here's an article (in Spanish) that could explain a few things about the time change. http://sociedad.elpais.com/sociedad/2013/09/25/actualidad/1380137001_972870.html

Comment: With DST people change clocks one hour back and fourth, and mealtimes change with the DST, so this doesn't explain anything.